# is it possible to use enum to parse the request in rust rocket

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I want to do a condition query in rust diesel(`diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono"] }`). read the docs from [here](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression/trait.BoxableExpression.html) and write the fuction like this:

```
fn find_channel(request: &ChannelRequest) -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::table, DB, SqlType=Bool> + '_> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::*;
    match request {
        ChannelRequest::editorPick(editorPick) => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(editorPick)),
        _ => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(0))
    }
}
```

but the function need the parameter was enum, and this is the `ChannelRequest`  define in rocket `rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }` :

```
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub enum ChannelRequest {
    userId(Option<i64>),
    pageNum(Option<i64>),
    pageSize(Option<i64>),
    editorPick(Option<i32>),
}
```

and this is the rocket api controller define:

```
#[post("/v1/page", data = "<request>")]
pub fn page(request: Json<ChannelRequest>) -> content::Json<String> {
    let channels = channel_query::<Vec<RssSubSource>>(&request);
    return box_rest_response(channels);
}
```

and this is the `channel_query`  which invoke the conditional query:

```
pub fn channel_query<T>(request: &Json<ChannelRequest>) -> PaginationResponse<Vec<RssSubSource>> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let query = rss_sub_source
        .filter(find_channel(&request.0))
        .order(created_time.desc())
        .paginate(1)
        .per_page(10);
    let query_result: QueryResult<(Vec<_>, i64, i64)> = query.load_and_count_pages_total::<RssSubSource>(&connection);
    let page_result = map_pagination_res(
        query_result,
        1,
        10);
    return page_result;
}
```

when I request the channel search api, seems the server side did not understand the client request, what should I do to using enum to receive the client request? is it possible? or what should I do to tweak the condition query function to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I tweak the match data type frome enum to struct, change the enum to strunct:

```
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ChannelRequest {
    pub userId: Option<i64>,
    pub pageNum: Option<i64>,
    pub pageSize: Option<i64>,
    pub editorPick: Option<i32>
}
```

and tweak the condition query like this:

```
fn find_channel(request: &ChannelRequest) -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::table, DB, SqlType=Bool> + '_> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::*;
    match request {
        ChannelRequest { editorPick, .. } => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(editorPick)),
        _ => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(0))
    }
}
```